# automate execution of python/capl script true pipeline on canoe

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, canoe

Im developing a pipeline that aim is to automate execution of capl tests on canoe

most simple test case
caplTest.py:

```
from win32com import client

canoe_app = None
canoe_app = client.Dispatch('CANoe.Application')
```

gitlab-ci job:

```
test powershell-script:
  tags:
    - Be2rig
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - $Env:UserName
    - $ENV:Path -split ';'
    - python --version
    - python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"
    - pip list
  script:
    - python caplTest.py
```

problem appear when script try to connect to canoe.

same code when executed on machine is working without any problem: opening canoe, execution of test , producing reports etc.

But while executed from piepline im getting a following error:

```
$ python caplTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\be2rig\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\NBaz6xW3\0\ci-pipeline\caplTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    canoe_app = client.Dispatch('CANoe.Application')
  File "C:\Users\be2rig\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\be2rig\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\be2rig\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)
```

I have registered a gitLab runner as current user
I have, according to documentation from vector, registered a 'COM Server'

Could you give me any clues what im missing or what else i shall try to